# How to convert a varchar into decimal but excepting one or more columns

Tags: sql, database

I have some problem with excepting one or more columns when I try to convert the varchar field into decimal.my statement is as below:

```
SELECT title, CAST(sumValues AS DECIMAL(9,2)
WHERE title != 'Total Clients') AS sumVal
FROM client_summary
```

I want to convert the `sumValues` field into decimal except for the column where the title is "Total Clients" (there is no decimal in counting persons). How possibly be my suitable statement for this?

Comment: try moving the WHERE clause to the end of the whole statement

Comment: create a function with two parameters

Comment: you may clarify if you wanna retrieve something (and if yes, what kind of data) for "sumVal" if title = 'TotalClients'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this : caution, all part of a `case...when...else` statement must return data of the same type (or implicit conversion).

```
SELECT title, 
CASE WHEN title <> 'Total Clients' 
 THEN CAST( sumValues AS DECIMAL(9,2)) 
 ELSE <something else which must also be decimal> --or no else
 END AS sumVal 
FROM client_summary
```

Edit : if you can't find a common type, you'll have to use two columns.

```
SELECT title, 
    CASE WHEN title <> 'Total Clients' 
     THEN CAST( sumValues AS DECIMAL(9,2)) 
     END AS sumVal,
    sumValues as allSumValues
 FROM client_summary
```

Comment: I forgot to say, I still wanted to display the value of "Total Client" but not in Decimal form. Your suggested code returns a null value for the "Total Client" column.

Comment: @JayMarz yes, but you have to choose a "common type". You can't retrieve a "column" with different types inside of it.